# Find any entities that contain any one string from a list

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I can't quite get my head around this one for some reason.

Say we have a class `Foo`

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And we have a generic list of them. I want to search through the generic list and pick out those that have a `Name` that contains any from a list of strings.

So something like

```
var source = GetListOfFoos();//assume a collection of Foo objects
var keywords = GetListOfKeyWords();//assume list/array of strings
var temp = new List<Foo>();
foreach(var keyword in keywords)
{
    temp.AddRange(source.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(keyword));
}
```

This issue here being a) the loop (doesn't feel optimal to me) and b) each object might appear more than once (if the name was 'Rob StackOverflow' and there was a keyword 'Rob' and keyword 'Stackoverflow').

I guess I could call `Distinct()` but again, it just doesn't feel optimal.

I think I'm approaching this incorrectly - what am I doing wrong?

---

Comment: So simple - sometimes you just need someone to point out the blindingly obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to search through the generic list and pick out those that have
>   a Name that contains any from a list of strings.

Sounds rather easy:

```
var query = source.Where(e => keywords.Any(k => e.Name.Contains(k)));
```

Add `ToList()` to get results as a `List<Foo>`:

```
var temp = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the keywords into a HashSet for fast lookup, so that you're not doing a N<sup>2</sup> loop.

```
HashSet<string> keywords = new HashSet<string>(GetListOfKeyWords(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

var query = source.Where(x => keywords.Contains(x.Name));
```

EDIT: Actually, I re-read the question, and was wrong. This will only match the entire keyword, not see if the Name contains the keyword. Working on a better fix.

I like MarcinJuraszek's answer, but I would also assume you want case-insensitive matching of the keywords, so I'd try something like this:

```
var query = source.Where(f => keywords.Any(k => f.Name.IndexOf(k, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

Comment: Good call, since the keyword collection is being built once and then accessed repeatedly.

Comment: Hmm. You didn't read the question wrong, it has been edited. The original version just matched name to keyword. :S